# How to manage BroadcastHub destinations

Tags: akka.net

Suppose I create a runnable, as follows:

```
var (sink, source) = MergeHub
        .Source<string>(perProducerBufferSize: 16)
        .ToMaterialized(BroadcastHub.Sink<string>(bufferSize: 256), Keep.Both)
        .Run(sys.Materializer());
```

I then want to dynamically add and remove Actor consumers of the BroadcastHub. I can do this:

```
var myProps = Props.Create<MyActor>();
var myActor = sys.System.ActorOf(myProps);
source.RunForeach(p => actor.Tell(p), myMaterializer);
```

(is this right?)

However I'd like to write a RegisterListener() and UnregisterListener() to add and remove actors that will receive the messages. Is there a good pattern for doing this? Usage would be:

```
 var myActor1 = ...
 RegisterListener(myActor1);
 var myActor2 = ...
 RegisterListener(myActor2);
 ...
 UnregisterListener(myActor2);
 UnregisterListener(myActor1);
```

If not, I can use a dictionary to keep track of registrations, but I didn't see an obvious way to have an actor stop listening and destroy that registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case sounds like an example of building broadcasted pub/sub over akka streams. [The official documentation](https://getakka.net/articles/streams/stream-dynamic.html#combining-dynamic-stages-to-build-a-simple-publish-subscribe-service) presents this example.